# JPEG 200 (aka J2K) handling in Silverlight app - any suggestions?

Tags: silverlight, jpeg2000

I need to handle [JPEG 2000](http://www.jpeg.org/jpeg2000/) (aka J2K) images in my silverlight app. Files stored either in the DB or file system on the server. Any suggestions how to handle them on the client? The only working converter I came across was written in Java. There are some ports to J#, but most likely they are not going to work on the client. The requirement is that the conversion should happen on the client to conserve the bandwidth and speed up the streaming of huge images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported by Silverlight and [.Net Image Tools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) don't support it too at the moment. So you have to write your own, port the (Java) version or ask the ImageTools developers if they can help you.

Comment: Yeah. I figured that much... Thanks for the link to the Net Image Tools though.